# What is the difference between pressure broadening and phonon broadening?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, acoustics, crystals, phonons

I have been reading chapter **5.2.2 Pressure broadening** and chapter **5.2.3 Phonon broadening** of the document [Paper BIII: Diatomic Molecules & Laser Physics by Prof. Simon Hooker](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/%7Ebhasbapat/phy420_files/moleculesandlasers.pdf). Chapter **5.2.3 Phonon broadening** says the following:

> The thermal vibrations of the lattice are quantized, the quantum of acoustic energy being termed a **phonon**.

But acoustic waves are just pressure (mechanical) waves, right? So then what is the fundamental difference between **pressure** broadening and **phonon** broadening?

Comment: *Pressure broadening* normally applies to gases and *phonon broadening* to solids. In your book is *pressure broadening* being used for a solid?

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes, now that you mention it, that does seem to be the case. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qualitative difference between pressure broadening and photon broadening is in the kinds of quanta that are colliding with a given atom to de-excite it.  Each kind of broadening happens when the an excited-state atom can collide inelastically with something else, leading to a non-electromagnetic de-excitation.  (Since this shortens the lifetime of the excited states, it broadens the width of the resulting spectral line, in accordance with the energy-time uncertainty relation.)

Pressure broadening occurs when you have an atom-atom (or atom-molecule or molecule-molecule) collision, with the excitation energy being carried away as kinetic energy of the two atoms after they collide.  Phonon broadening occurs when when a quantized sound wave strikes the excited atom, and the scattered phonon absorbs the excitation energy from the atom.

In a fluid, there is a transition region between the two kinds of broadening.  At low densities, the meaningful collisions are of the pressure type; however, as the density increases toward the strongly hydrodynamic regime (as in a liquid), it makes more sense to talk about (longitudinal) phonons as the dominant excitations of the fluid.  There is no sharp demarcation therefore between the two, in fluids.  In solids, however, there are no loose-flying atoms to collide with an excited atom, so the broadening is entirely dominated by inelastic scattering of phonons.

Comment: I'd like to add that the collisions don't neccessarily deexcite the atom. A random phase jump during the emission caused by the collision also broadens the spectrum.